# Regex to replace all curly braces except for the case '{0}'

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

I want to validate a string:

- it may contain zero to many occurrences of `{0}`
- all other occurrences of { or } must be removed.

So: `'AbC{de{0} x{1}}'` must become `'AbCde{0} x1'`

I tried this:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, @"({|})+(?!{0})", string.Empty);
```

But that gives me the error:

> Regex issue: Quantifier(x,y) following nothing.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(\{0})|[{}]", "$1")
```

Or, to support any ASCII digits inside `{...}`,

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(\{[0-9]+})|[{}]", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%7B0%7D%29%7C%5B%7B%7D%5D&i=AbC%7Bde%7B0%7D%20x%7B1%7D%7D&r=%241)

**Details**

- `(\{0})` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` refers to this value from the replacement string): a `{0}` substring
- `|` - or
- `[{}]`  - a `{` or `}`.

Another approach with lookarounds is possible:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"{(?!0})|(?<!{0)}", string.Empty)
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%28%3F!0%7D%29%7C%28%3F%3C!%7B0%29%7D&i=AbC%7Bde%7B0%7D%20x%7B1%7D%7D&r=). Here, `{(?!0})` matches a `{` not followed with `0}` and `(?<!{0)}` matches a `}` not preceded with `{0`.

Comment: I like the lookaround approach best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookarounds o achieve your goal: `\{(?!0\})|(?<!\{0)\}`

Explanation:

`\{(?!0\})` - match `{` if it's not followed by `0}` (due to negative lookahead)

`|` - alternation

`(?<!\{0)\}` -  match `}` if it's not preceded by `{0` (due to negative lookbehind)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUKgwq/1)

Code sample:

```
Regex.Replace("AbC{de{0} x{1}}", @"{(?!0\})|(?<!\{0)\}", "")
```

Comment: This solution is already posted in my answer. With details and a demo. Why duplicate?